Is it possible to use the latest blockhash to get transaction data for the block its for?
Hello i hope you are all having nice days!
I wanted to ask if I could use the latest blockhash in order to get transactions relating to its block, or if I could get the current slot and use that with getblock to then get transaction details after
Thanks.

The getBlock RPC method takes in a slot number, so you can't use the blockhash as an input.
You'll need to get the current confirmed slot using getSlot https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getslot, ie:
$ curl https://api.devnet.solana.com -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1, "method":"getSlot", "params": [{"commitment": "confirmed"}]}
'

More info at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getblock
